# image from video is black

Tags: graphics, image-conversion

I have been trying to grab an image from video using Print Screen. When I view it in Irfan View it looks perfectly normal, but when I try to upload it to Stack Exchange the image is black. I even screen shotted the Irfan View image, so it is second generation, yet the image is STILL black:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to grab a frame using FFMPEG? Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi  -r 1 -t  40 -ss  01:30:14 image-%d.jpeg
```